# What's the difference between Holding Point and Hold Short?

Tags: phraseology

I heard some ATCos requesting pilots to report, on holding point, and also hold short. Is there any difference on them?

Answer (score 3):

#### The U.S. and holding point

It depends on the locale and context. For taxiing in the US **holding point** is not used as the FAA ATC manual refers to it as an ICAO term for a visual (or otherwise) holding point in the sky.

> **HOLDING POINT [ICAO]−** A specified location,
> identified by visual or other means, in the vicinity of
> which the position of an aircraft in flight is
> maintained in accordance with air traffic control
> clearances.

---

#### Elsewhere and hold short

Elsewhere for taxiing, holding point is where the intended departure will take place **from a runway.** Check [eurocontrol.int](https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/phraseology/) for examples (direct linking not available), but here's an example they give:

> TAXI TO **HOLDING POINT** [number] [RUNWAY (number)] VIA (specific route to be followed), [**HOLD SHORT** OF RUNWAY (number)] or [CROSS RUNWAY (number)]. [REPORT VACATED]

- Taxi to holding point A, runway 36, via A.

That means take A all the way to the end where it meets runway 36 and stop at the hold short line or behind whoever is ahead.

- Taxi to holding point C, runway 36, via A and C.

Here the runway was shortened (an intersection departure) and the pilot will hold at C and then line up from C when cleared.

**Report holding point** means report when you get there.

- Tower, Stack 1 is at holding point A, fully ready.

**Hold short** is the same everywhere and applies to any intersection or runway on the way to the runway/gate.

- Taxi to holding point A, runway 36, via A, hold short C.

Here the pilot will hold where C meets A and awaits clearance to continue.

---

**Hold your position** is an instruction to stop right now.

Some airports employ **LAHSO** (Land and Hold Short Operations), where a hold short line exists on the runway you are landing on.

- Example: Cleared to land runway 27, hold short runway 22L.

Example in [Boston Logan](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KBOS) (blue circle):

[image]

Comment: `visual holding point in the sky` — _virtual_ point in the sky?

Comment: @egid - good catch, it says `identified by visual or other means`, I didn't realize I left a part out.

Answer (score 1):

The holding point is usually a fix in the STAR where aircraft are "held" flying a pre-defined radial for traffic congestion purposes; and I have only heard it in context of ATC referring to aircraft flying.

Holding *short* is very important. It means stopping before entering a *runway area* and is marked by two solid lines. You should hold short (ie, before) the solid lines.

Here is a picture of an aircraft that is stopped short (source: google maps of OMDB):

[image]

The lines are marked as two solid lines, followed by dashed lines; the holding side is on the solid lines:

[image]

(Source: propilotmag.com)

The holding *position* however, is a place on the ground where aircraft are to report once they taxi to it.

From the OMDB AIP:

> Red inset lights supplemented with elevated lights on either side of
>   the holding position. Runway holding positions (CAT I and CAT II /
>   III) and intermediate holding positions for general service road
>   crossings are provided with Stop Bar Lighting.
>
> RWY Guard Lights: RWY holding positions are provided with a pair of
>   yellow flashing lights on either side of the Stop bar
>
> Intermediate Holding Position Lights: A set of three amber lights or
>   full red stop bar are provided at intermediate TWY holding positions.

Source : [DCGA Website](https://www.gcaa.gov.ae/aip/current/AIRACs/2017-P05/html/eAIP/AD-2.OMDB-en-GB.html)

Further on the same page:

> 2.20.5.2.2 Pilots in receipt of a conditional line-up clearance on a preceding departing aircraft shall remain behind the subject aircraft
>   but may cross the runway holding point, subject to no illuminated red
>   stop bar and then enter the runway upon receipt of the clearance.
>   There is no requirement for the subject aircraft to have commenced
>   take-off roll before entering the runway. Pilots must be aware that
>   there may be a blast hazard as the aircraft on the runway applies
>   power.

However, ATC may give an instruction on the ground such as:

> November 5 Bravo, taxi to holding point Charlie Runway 30R

This usually refers to a physical holding position.